# Network driver for Fujitsu-Siemens Scaleo J PC

Tags: windows, home-networking, windows-server-2003, network-adapter

I have just acquired a handed down mini-tower PC claiming to be a Fujitsu-Siemens Scaleo J (on the case).  The only text I could find on the motherboard is p4m800-pro-M.

I have reached a point installing Windows Server 2003 (SBS, via MSDN) where a NIC is required, yet Windows does not recognise the installed NIC.  The cable seems fine, green lights are on on both sides, i.e. my DSL router and the PC.

I can't find any working links for drivers for the Scaleo J, yet lots for various guises of p4m800-pro.  The first I tried has had no effect on the OS recognising and dealing with the NIC.  Any advice will be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, have you tried out Belarc if it can perhaps find *some* information on that NIC? Maybe even an FCC number or something?

http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html

Also here is the manual for the motherboard, maybe this will help: http://uk.ts.fujitsu.com/rl/servicesupport/techsupport/Boards/Motherboards/ECS/P4M800Pro-M/Man_P4M800Pro-M_uk.pdf

Here are the drivers from the direct website: You can also see the [NIC drivers here.](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Downloads/ProductsDetail_Download.aspx?detailid=552&DetailName=Driver&DetailDesc=&CategoryID=1&MenuID=6&LanID=9)

Comment: the NIC is a VIA® VT6103L 10/100 Mbps Fast Ethernet PHY

Comment: Belarc reports "Communications: None detected", Mac address: all 0's.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the drivers from the [board manufacturer](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Products/ProductsDetail.aspx?detailid=673&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Driver&MenuID=44&LanID=0) (ECS)?

and here's a direct download link for the VIA VT6103 Rhine (PHY) [network driver](http://www.viaarena.com/Driver/via_rhine_ndis5_v384a.zip) from the chip manufacturer (VIA).

> supported operating systems:
>
> Windows Vista 64-Bit, Windows Vista
>   32-Bit, Windows XP, Windows 2000,
>   Windows ME, Windows NT, Windows XP
>   64-Bit, Windows 95, Windows 98,
>   Windows 98SE